# replacing all numbers by a single word in text files

Tags: bash

Is there a easy and efficient one line solution to replace all the numbers or sequences that contain numbers and symbols (\ / $ & * # @ ) ( - + ! ~ . , : ; " ' ` ^ % _ ] [ { } = ), for example:

```
1 2 3 4 998898321321
0.2 1.2 32221.111. 1321321321.111
111.11212.21212
212323/12331/321312
121-12123-32131
121+12123+32131
1_212121_2320
12131!~~~323131
etc
```

with a single token NUMBER in a huge text (100GB) file? Sample input and output:

input:

```
hello my friend 212323/12331/321312
hope you are fine 12131!~~~323131 in 33-years from now
happy face is important to maintaion by 98987 321321/32131
```

output:

```
hello my friend NUMBER
hope you are fine NUMBER in 33-years from now
happy face is important to maintaion by NUMBER NUMBER
```

Basically anything between two space that contains numbers and non-alphabetic symbols must be replaced by NUMBER. The rest of the text should be kept as-is.

Comment: Do you have a free 100GB to write the modified output?

Comment: What characters are "symbols"?

Comment: \ / $ & * # @ ) ( [ ] { } - + ! ~ . , : ; " ' ` ^ % _ =  whitespace

Comment: so, any non-alpha? And I was serious about the 100GB free storage (even `sed -i` writes to a temp file)

Comment: yes, any non-alphanumeric combination with numbers.

Comment: Try `sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]\+/NUMBER/g'`.

Comment: What happens if the word `foo33bar` appears in the fiel?

Comment: @alvits, I think you need to ensure there's at least one digit in there.

Comment: that must be kept as-is. the purpose is to reduce the web crawled files by replacing numbers which occur very often by a single token. I do have TiB s of disk space ...

Comment: @user3639557, please provide better input data, and show what the output should look like.

Comment: And also what the output of that input would have to be.

Comment: Added sample input and output.

Comment: Try `sed 's/\(\s*\)[^[:alpha:][:blank:]]\+\(\s\|$\)/\1NUMBER\2/g'`.

Comment: Honestly, this seems like a fun code golf for the PPCG community. Consider moving it/reposting it there, you will get your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I got this:

I need three steps:

1. Double up the white spaces
2. Replace all non-letter characters surrounded by a space or newline with NUMBER (while retaining the spaces)
3. Collapse double white spaces into single ones

This is how it looks now:

```
$ cat test.txt
hello my friend 212323/12331/321312
hope you are fine 12131!~~~323131 in 33-years from now
happy face is important to maintaion by 98987 321321/32131
123 This is a line

$ sed -r 's/ /  /g;s/(^| )[^[:alpha:] ]+( |$)/\1NUMBER\2/g;s/  / /g' test.txt
hello my friend NUMBER
hope you are fine NUMBER in 33-years from now
happy face is important to maintaion by NUMBER NUMBER
NUMBER This is a line
```

Comment: Nice. But not exactly what I needed. I need to replace the full "212323/12331/32131" with a single token "NUMBER"

Comment: Well done - the doubling of the spaces allows true isolation of all tokens of interest. It may not be needed here, but how would you generalize it to handle any mix of spaces and _tabs_?

Comment: I'd wing it somehow ;) Probably by adding a space after every space or tab, then afterwards deleting every space that follows a space or a tab. The main replacement would have to be adapted, because a tab could follow a number.

Comment: That may work, but it gets messy; if use of `perl` is an option, its look-around assertions provide a superior alternative that bypasses this problem altogether.

Comment: True, if I had to look at a 100GB file, I might actually look for more elaborate solutions than just a `sed` script.

Comment: This is still not perfect :). It replaces all punctuations . with NUMBER.

Comment: Welcome to the intricacies of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

To complement [chw21's helpful solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34146967/45375) with a `perl` solution that can handle not just spaces, but *any mix of spaces and tabs between words*:

```
perl -ple 's/(^|(?<=[[:blank:]]))[^[:alpha:][:blank:]]+((?=[[:blank:]])|$)/NUMBER/g' file
```

The use of look-behind (`(?<=...`) and look-ahead (`(?=...)`) assertions obviates the need for capture groups, and therefore the need for doubling spaces as an intermediate step; using `[[:blank:]]` (space or tab) in lieu of  (just space) makes it work with any mix of spaces and tabs:

- `(^|(?<=[[:blank:]]))` matches the beginning of a line (`^`) or any character preceded by a blank (space or tab)
- `[^[:alpha:][:blank:]]+` matches any nonempty run of characters composed of only non-letters and non-blanks
- `((?=[[:blank:]])|$)` matches at the end of the line (`$`) or if the following character is a blank.